# jquery/ajax load scripts - best practices

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to get the hang of using ajax loads (mostly via jquery) to make my site more efficient.  Wondering if anyone can provide any suggestions re "best practices" for using ajax?

Is there a way to simplify a script for multiple ajax calls?  For example, I currently have the working script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dog').click(function () {
      $('#body').load("dog.html");      
  });
  $('#cat').click(function () {
      $('#body').load("cat.html");      
  });
  $('#bird').click(function () {
      $('#body').load("bird.html");     
  });
  $('#lizard').click(function () {
      $('#body').load("lizard.html");       
  });
});
```

The script just gets longer and longer with each additional function.  Is there a simpler, more efficient way to write this script to cover multiple load scripts?

Also, should I be using ajax loads to replace the majority of actual links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, since the code you posted seems to have a pattern between the `id` and the `filename`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'commonParentElementHere', function (e) {
        $('#body').load(e.target.id + ".html");
    });
});
```

This suggestion uses .on() and you just need to add a `commonParentElementHere`, a id or a class of the common parent of those elements.

**Another option** is to use a class on all elements that should be clickable, and then use the code passing the id to the html file name, like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.theCOmmonClass', function () {
        $('#body').load(this.id + ".html");
    });
});
```

Comment: @user3180105, great! Glad I could help! Feel free to click to accept the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say give all the elements you want to click on a class say `ajax` then.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ajax').click(function () {
      $('#body').load(this.id + ".html");      
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `id` matches the file name the script can be simplified to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dog,#cat,#bird,#lizard').click(function () {
      var fileName = this.id + ".html";
      $('#body').load(fileName);      
  });
});
```

This script simply specifies each `id` in a single selector that separates each `id` with a comma.  This will calls the `click` function to be fired for each element.  With the anonymous function attached to the click event, the `id` of each element is obtained and concatenated to create the file name which is then passed to the `load` function.

If the `id` doesn't always match the `element` you could use the following approach.

```
var mappings = [
   {id: "fileName1", file:"file.html"},
   {id: "fileName2", file:"file2.html"}
];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < mappings; i++){
            createMapping(mappings[i]);
        }

        function createMapping(mapping){
            $("#" + mapping.id).click(function(){
               $('#body').load(mapping.file);      
            });
        }
    });
```